# Location coordinates are not nill yet labels don't get updated when app is loaded but get loaded if I come back from another screen tho

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit, core-location

I have defined a global variable to store location coordinates and im updating location in `Appdelegate` as soon as the app launches. Here's the code for that:

```
var locationManager:CLLocationManager!

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
     // Override point for customization after application launch.
        
      window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        
      determineCurrentLocation()
        
      self.pushToHomeScreen()
        
      return true
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        if GlobalUserManager.shared.currentLocation == nil {
            GlobalUserManager.shared.currentLocation = locations.last
            locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        }
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print("Error - locationManager: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

    //MARK:- Intance Methods
    func determineCurrentLocation() {
        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }
    }
```

After this the Home Screen opens where I have two labels to show location data. It didn't get update when Homescreen is loaded for both cases when I tried to update by putting code in `viewdidLoad()` and `viewWillAppear()`. So I tried putting code in `viewDidAppear()` and its something like this:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        if GlobalUserManager.shared.currentLocation != nil {
            lblLat.text = GlobalUserManager.shared.currentLocation.latitude
            lblLong.text = GlobalUserManager.shared.currentLocation.longitude
        }
        else {
            lblLat.text = "Lat not available"
            lblLong.text = "Long not available"
        }
    }
```

When screen is loaded, labels are empty which means at least `GlobalUserManager.shared.currentLocation != nil` but I want them to get updated as soon as screen is loaded. Instead I have to click another page and come back and then they are updated.

Comment: It takes time to get the location. You need to notify your view to update when you receive the location. You could use `NotificationCenter`, for example. To get a one-off location it is better to use `requestLocation` rather than stopping updates after one result; the initial result may not be accurate. `requestLocation` tries to get an accurate location before presenting it to your app.

Comment: I tried it, printing value, it does give location value however when I use it to pass to a func which sets labels, still not working